# Reversed version of de Bruijn's identity/Boltzmann H-theorem for Markov processes

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process, entropy, lyapunov-functions, information-geometry

Take a Markov process $X_t$ on a Polish state-space $E$. Suppose the Markov process has invariant measure $\mu$ and is prepared with initial distribution $\mu_0\ll \mu$. De Bruijn's identity says that the relative entropy of the law of $X_t$ wrt the stationary measure $\mu$ is always decreasing, and the rate of decrease is given by the Fisher information $I$
\begin{equation*}
    \frac{d}{dt}H \left(\mu_t \| \mu \right) = - I \left(\mu_t, \mu\right) \leq 0
\end{equation*}

Do we have the similar property of
$H \left( \mu   \|\mu_t\right)$ also decreasing over time? And what can we say about $\frac{d}{dt}H \left( \mu   \|\mu_t\right)$?

EDIT: Baez and Pollard show in equation (14) of their paper *Relative Entropy in Biological Systems* (2016) that $\frac{d}{dt}H \left( \mu   \|\mu_t\right)\leq 0$ for any finite state-space Markov process. However, they do not discuss the general case.